# SSRS Grouping on a field, even when there are duplicates

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I have a report in Reporting Services and there is a group that is based around a field value.  I want the group to repeat itself on the report as many times as there are rows with that field.  The problem is that using `Field!field.Value` seems to only pull distinct values.  Since my dataset has rows that have duplicate values, they are not all showing.

When I declare my parent group, is there a way to tell it to group on every row in the parent group, not just the distinct rows?

Alternatively, is there a list of other options I can use other than just `.Value` on my field?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the RowNumber function (not adding it into the dataset) as an expression to group on?

I don't have a report in front of me right now, but I think that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a second field that you can use a "dummy" (aka tie breaker, key etc), to include in the grouping to make it unique?

This is how I'd do it.

Edit: after comment.

Can you add a calculated field to the dataset, such as [Rownumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225.aspx) to act as one?

Edit 2: I mean in SSRS itself: ["Calculated field"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156295(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: I wish there was.  Unfortunately, there is bad duplicate data in the system, however, I am trying to recreate an old report that was based off of XSLT previously and as sad as it is, I have to recreate its errors.  It is a University Transcript and the new ones have to be identical to the old ones.

Comment: While that would work with a regular query, I am unfortunately using a stored procedure, so I suppose I can't really add anything like that to it.